# Should I submit my math subject GRE score? (Engineering undergraduate applying for Applied Math MS)

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, masters, united-states, gre

I scored **740 (63 percentile)** in the math subject GRE. I am applying for a masters in Applied Math in the US. Given most unis have the GRE requirement optional, would submitting the score affect my application positively/negatively/neither?

PS : I studied electronics engg in undergrad. So was wondering if I should submit the score to strengthen my application (if it does).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a direct answer, but note that no single thing is determinative in the US. Note that the math GRE test is quite difficult, even for those who have studied math as a major in undergraduate work.

Also note that applied math is quite different from pure math. So, it is difficult to say whether it is a "strengthening" outcome. You also don't say which math courses you have taken in your program, but the GRE test emphasis is on calculus (broadly speaking) and abstract algebra.

The other problem with a prediction is that applications are evaluated by individuals with their own ideas about importance. Make sure that your other indicators of success are strong, especially letters of recommendation. In that case, the score probably doesn't matter much.

Yet another factor is the nature of the program(s) you are applying to and the likely competition there.

Perhaps (perhaps) it is better to omit non required things that aren't obviously positive.